# How to convert recursion to iteration?

Tags: java, recursion, iteration

This question is asked few times but I still find it quite difficult to convert easily readable and intuitive code into iterative code. For example I was practicing a coding question and I am given 26 integers which indicate how many times each character appears in the string. I should print all possible strings. Following is my recursive code

```
private static void combinatorial(String prefix, ArrayList<Integer> remainingToFill,
        int totalLength) {
    if (prefix.length() == totalLength) {
        System.out.println(prefix);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < remainingToFill.size(); i++) {
        if (remainingToFill.get(i) > 0) {
            ArrayList<Integer> toFill = new ArrayList<>(remainingToFill);
            toFill.set(i, toFill.get(i) - 1);
            combinatorial(prefix + (char) ('a' + i), toFill, totalLength);
        }
    }
}
```

I coded iterative version of this but the resultant function is much more complex and not readable and took more time for me to code it. How do I tackle this kind of problem? Is there any simple technique I can follow which would lead to easy and readable code?

Comment: does this help? http://blog.moertel.com/posts/2013-05-11-recursive-to-iterative.html

Comment: I don't suspect a universal pattern exists for this.  (Though, if I'm mistaken, I'd love to learn about it.)  Any given operation would be performed differently.  Some are "simpler" as a recursive implementation, some are "simpler" as an iterative implementation, some are something else entirely.  And the implementation chosen would depend heavily on the capabilities and intricacies of the language used.  If a given operation is "ugly" when implemented with a given pattern, then it's likely that the wrong pattern is being used.  I wouldn't expect a meaningful translation between the two.

Comment: IMO recursion is based on `call stack` so you have to emulate that stack in `iterative pattern` to achieve the desired result however it may not be the best solution.

Comment: Well I think your code isn't a perfect recursive. Its a mix of both iterations and recursions. That's why it might be complex to convert in the first place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, the reason programming languages support recursive expression of programs is that it's often simpler than explicit iterative forms. So your question is almost self-answering.

However, there *really is a methodical way to convert recursive forms to iterative forms that always works*.  It helps to have a language with `goto`, which Java doesn't.

First let's clean up the java. We want to use a minimum number of arguments and local variables because what's left must go on our explicit stack. Here we go. We do away with all except `i` and `prefix`.

```
class CombinationLister {
  private final int[] counts;
  private final int length;

  CombinationLister(int[] counts) {
    this.counts = counts.clone();
    this.length = Arrays.stream(counts).sum();
  }

  private void list(String prefix) {
    if (prefix.length() == length) {
      System.out.println(prefix);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
      if (counts[i] > 0) {
        --counts[i];
        list(prefix + (char) ('a' + i));
        ++counts[i];
      }
    }
  }

  void run() {
    list("");
  }
}
```

Now let's transcribe to C, which has `goto`. Here it's easy to eliminate even `prefix` by adding a global string buffer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char str[100];
int counts[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int n_counts = 3;
int total_count = 6;
int len = 0;

void list(void) {
  if (len == total_count) printf("%.*s\n", total_count, str);
  for (int i = 0; i < n_counts; i++) {
    if (counts[i] > 0) {
      str[len] = 'a' + i;
      --counts[i];
      ++len;
      list();
      --len;
      ++counts[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Now, the rules are:

- Build a stack of records with one field for each local variable and parameter. Here we have only `i` left, so we don't even need records. A stack of `int`s will do.
- Replace the recursive call site with

  - a `push` onto the stack, then
  - reset the parameters to their new values (here we don't have any), then
  - jump to the start of the function, and
  - immediately after the jump, put a label `rtn:`.
- At the end of the function, add an epilog that checks whether the stack is empty. If not, it pops the stack and jumps to `rtn:`.

These rules essentially mimic the code the compiler will generate to handle recursive calls.

Putting it all together, we have:

```
int stk[100];
int p = 0; // stack pointer

void list(void) {
  int i;
 start:
  if (len == total_count) printf("%.*s\n", total_count, str);
  for (i = 0; i < n_counts; i++) {
    if (counts[i] > 0) {
      str[len] = 'a' + i;
      --counts[i];
      ++len;
      stk[p++] = i;  // push i on stack
      goto start;
     rtn:
      --len;
      ++counts[i];
    }
  }
  // epilog
  if (p > 0) {
    i = stk[--p];  // restore i from stack
    goto rtn;
  }
}
```

If you follow the steps carefully, your code will run first try every time.  The only additional tip is that when there is more than one recursive call site, you'll need one return label for each `rtn1:`, `rtn2:`, etc. and an extra `int` field in the stack that connotes the return site, with a switch statement in the epilog to jump to the correct one.

Of course this isn't pretty code. We'd like to get rid of the `goto`s. It turns out this is always possible by doing "algebra" to convert the `gotos` to loops.  There are a couple of dozen transformation techniques...too many to describe here.  It's a lot like simplifying an equation in math class. Sometimes it's necessary to add Boolean flags. In this case, though, we don't need to. I finished with this:

```
void list(void) {
  for (int i = 0;;) {
    while (i < n_counts && counts[i] == 0) i++;
    if (i < n_counts) {
      --counts[i];
      str[len] = 'a' + i;
      stk[p++] = i;
      if (++len == total_count) printf("%.*s\n", total_count, str);
      i = 0;
    } else if (p > 0) {
      i = stk[--p];
      --len;
      ++counts[i++];
    }
    else break;
  }
}
```

Just for fun, back to Java:

```
class CombinationLister {
  private final int[] counts;
  private final char[] str;
  private final int[] stk;
  private int p = 0;
  private int len = 0;

  CombinationLister(int[] counts) {
    this.counts = counts.clone();
    this.str = new char[Arrays.stream(counts).sum()];
    this.stk = new int[str.length];
  }

  void run() {
    for (int i = 0;;) {
      while (i < counts.length && counts[i] == 0) i++;
      if (i < counts.length) {
        --counts[i];
        str[len] = (char) ('a' + i);
        stk[p++] = i;
        if (++len == str.length) System.out.println(str);
        i = 0;
      } else if (p > 0) {
        i = stk[--p];
        --len;
        ++counts[i++];
      } else break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void combinatorial(ArrayList<Integer> remainingToFill, int totalLength) {
    Stack st = new Stack();
    st.push( new Pair<String,Integer>("", 0) );
    while( !st.empty() ){
        Pair<String,Integer> top = (Pair<String,Integer>) st.pop();
        String prefix = top.getKey();
        Integer i = top.getValue();
        if (prefix.length() == totalLength) {
            System.out.println(prefix);
            int index= prefix.charAt(prefix.length()-1 )-'a' ;
            remainingToFill.set( index , remainingToFill.get(index) + 1 );
        }
        else{
            if( i== remainingToFill.size() ){
                if( prefix.length()>0 ){
                    int index= prefix.charAt(prefix.length()-1 )-'a' ;
                    remainingToFill.set( index , remainingToFill.get(index) + 1 );
                }
            }
            else{
                st.push( new Pair<String,Integer>(prefix, i+1) );
                if( remainingToFill.get(i) > 0 ){
                    remainingToFill.set(i, remainingToFill.get(i) - 1);
                    st.push( new Pair<String,Integer>(prefix+(char)('a'+i), 0) );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```